# Is it possible that only using k8s woker node on-premise, but using master node managed by cloud vender(aws,gcp.. etc)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

Is it possible that only using k8s woker node on-premise, but using master node managed by cloud vender(aws,gcp.. etc)?

I want to take advantage of managed service on k8s master node, but my company already have lots of servers on-premise. And also we have Cloud interconnect connection between GCP and on-premise.

I've read Anthos related documentation a few times. However, nowhere is the usage of mixing one k8s cluster in on-prem and cloud.

Comment: I would say no, because it's not a real good idea. In case of interruption of communication between the on prem node and the on cloud master, you don't have any orchestration (the on prem cluster can't work in standalone). In addition, when you set up your K8S master, you provide it all the required config to create node, loadbalancer, firewall rules (...) on the environment. Here, how the cloud master can know your on prem environment and configuration? All of these things sound odd and strange

Answer (score 0):

This is something I have not tried, but let me share my thoughts with you.

When we setup a cluster say multiple masters and multiple worker nodes, we need to have the possibility of two way communication between the masters and workers; that is kube-apiservers in masters and kubelets in worker nodes need to connect to each other. So, that is something we need to check.

Also, if you are using NodePort based routing, then there will be a requirement for all the workers and masters to forward traffic to each other. For example, if a NodePort request comes to a master node, then will have to forward it to worker node (like wise).

I think there might be other points as well, but documented the things I felt.